# How can I fix RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox object was given an infinite size during layout?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Code:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class BeerListPage extends StatefulWidget {
  BeerListPage({required Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  BeerListPageState createState() => BeerListPageState();
}

class BeerListPageState extends State<BeerListPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: new Container(
          child: new Center(
            child: new FutureBuilder(
                future:
                DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString('packages/beers/beers.json'),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  var beers = json.decode(snapshot.data.toString());

                  return new ListView.builder(shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      var beer = beers[index];
                      return new Card(
                        child: new Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            new Text("Name: " + beer['name'],
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 24)),
                            new Text("Country: " + beer['country'],
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, fontSize: 20)),
                            new Text("ABV: " + beer['abv'],
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, fontSize: 20)),
                            new Image.network(beer['image'], height: 200)
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    itemCount: beers == null ? 0 : beers.length,
                  );
                }),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Error messages:
A RenderFlex overflowed by Infinity pixels on the bottom.
RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox object was given an infinite size during layout.
_RenderInkFeatures object was given an infinite size during layout.
RenderPhysicalModel object was given an infinite size during layout.
The relevant error-causing widget was:
Scaffold file:///C:/Users/Miche/AndroidStudioProjects/untitled/lib/beer_list.dart:17:12

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class BeerListPage extends StatefulWidget {
  BeerListPage({required Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  BeerListPageState createState() => BeerListPageState();
}

class BeerListPageState extends State<BeerListPage> {
  final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: new Container(
          height: size.height,
          width: double.infinity,
          child: new Center(
            child: new FutureBuilder(
                future:
                DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString('packages/beers/beers.json'),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  var beers = json.decode(snapshot.data.toString());

                  return new ListView.builder(shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      var beer = beers[index];
                      return new Card(
                        child: new Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            new Text("Name: " + beer['name'],
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 24)),
                            new Text("Country: " + beer['country'],
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, fontSize: 20)),
                            new Text("ABV: " + beer['abv'],
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, fontSize: 20)),
                            new Image.network(beer['image'], height: 200)
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    itemCount: beers == null ? 0 : beers.length,
                  );
                }),
          ),
        );
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to fix that issue without giving height. Any possibilities?